# boldface with italic cannot be done in the second main header of advanced tables in memoir class, why?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{}
\small
\begin{tabular}
{S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=1.2]}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Geometric Arguements} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Line Arguements}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{PSP Arguements}\\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
{$A_b$} & {$B_c/D$} & {\textbf{$E_f/G$}} & {$H_i/J$} & {$K_l/P_{\mathrm{mp}} - D_s/P_{\mathrm{mp}}$}\\
\midrule
9.85  & 8.89  & \textbf{\textit{7.85}} & \textbf{\textit{2.58}} & 0.57 \\
8.83    & 5.79  & \textbf{\textit{5.92}} & \textbf{\textit{3.39}} & 0.68 \\ 
4.47    & 3.42  & \textbf{\textit{3.68}} & \textbf{\textit{8.54}} & 0.78 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\caption{Arguements caption \label{tab:table_five}}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output of the table is given below

[image]:

**Doubt 1:**
The problem in the top red round in the header is that neither a bold face type nor an italic text or with both simultaneously is cumbersome to create it. Any ideas?

**Doubt 2:**
When two columns with bold and italic numbers are created, the numbers in the second column (which is red rounded) does not get seated at proper place no matter how possibly it is adjusted. why is it so? How to place in the proper place i.e. exactly below Hi/J as other columns.

Comment: It's still *arguments*, not *arguements*

Comment: `\textbf` and `\textit` do not affect math mode constructs in their scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re Doubt 1: If you want to set math material in bold, use a directive such as `\mathversion{bold}`; `\boldmath` works too. `\textbf` is not correct here.

Re Doubt 2: If you want all entries in a column of type `S` to be typeset in ***bold italics***, it's a good idea to provide this information in the column definition, via a specification such as

```
>{\bfseries\itshape}S[table-format=1.2,detect-all]
```

That way, you won't have to remember to type `\bfseries\itshape` (or something equivalent) at the start of each cell in question.

[image]

That said, I think that using both italics and bold is too much of a good thing -- and thus no longer good. Use one or the other typographic device to create emphasis, ***but not both***.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{S[table-format=1.2]} 
         *{2}{>{\bfseries\itshape}S[table-format=1.2,detect-all]} 
         S[table-format=1.2]}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Geometric Arguments} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Line Arguments}}  
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{PSP Arguments}\\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}
{$A_b$} & {$B_c/D$} & {\mathversion{bold}$E_f/G$} & {\mathversion{bold}$H_i/J$} & {$K_l/P_{\mathrm{mp}} - D_s/P_{\mathrm{mp}}$}\\
\midrule
9.85    & 8.89  & 7.85 & 2.58 & 0.57 \\
8.83    & 5.79  & 5.92 & 3.39 & 0.68 \\ 
4.47    & 3.42  & 3.68 & 8.54 & 0.78 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Arguments caption} 
\label{tab:table_five}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by specifying the font in the cells where you want boldface italic; also, common words in the header can better be placed just once: it happens that the sum of the natural width of the third and fourth columns is less than the width of “Line Arguments”, so the excess goes to the fourth column, causing misalignment.

For making the header boldface, since it's just math, use `\boldmath`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\newcommand{\bfit}{\bfseries\itshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering

\small
\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Arguments} \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
 & {Geometric} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Line}}  & {PSP}\\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
{$A_b$} & {$B_c/D$} & {\boldmath$E_f/G$} & {\boldmath$H_i/J$} & {$K_l/P_{\mathrm{mp}} - D_s/P_{\mathrm{mp}}$}\\
\midrule
9.85    & 8.89  & \bfit 7.85 & \bfit 2.58 & 0.57 \\
8.83    & 5.79  & \bfit 5.92 & \bfit 3.39 & 0.68 \\ 
4.47    & 3.42  & \bfit 3.68 & \bfit 8.54 & 0.78 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Arguments caption\label{tab:table_five}}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

*Don't use `adjustbox` if you don't need it. It does no real harm, but it just add useless overhead.

[image]